# How to filter dynamically in strapi with qs

Tags: strapi, qs

I need to create a simple filter on `strapi` together with `qs`.

All these parameters are optional and are added by clicking on the checkbox.

The problem is that I can't make a filter based on an array, I use `$in` to match the values from the incoming array with the server and get an error

[image]

```js
export interface responseFilterType {
    type_product?: [string]
    user_type?: [string]
    weight?: string | number
}
```

[image]

```js
qs.stringify({
        populate: "*",
        filters: {
            $and: [
                {
                    ...(value.type_product && {
                        type_product: {
                            $in: value.type_product,
                        }
                    })
                },
                {
                    ...(value.user_type && {
                        user_type: {
                            $in: value.user_type,
                        }
                    })
                }
            ] ,

        },
    }, {
        encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify URL
    });
```

data from server

[image]

Main type

[image]

type_product & user_type

[image]

Comment: I don’t think you actually need $in in this case, I think $in can be safely omitted, by passing an array. However it’s not clear what props are in strapi. You need to append schema.json of your content type, then it will be possible to help you with query…

Comment: @antokhio Проще говоря у меня есть функция с `qs` которая возвращает строку. В функцию приходит объект с типом `responseFilterType`, при этом в объекте поля могут быть пустыми.  `$in` я использую для того чтобы проверить массив `type_product`, есть ли там значение из бд. Вроде все логично, но не могу понять что к чему. Вижу Вы знаете русский, мне так проще будет выразить мысли

Comment: Simply put, I have a function with qs that returns a string. The function receives an object with the response Filter Type type, while the fields in the object may be empty. I use $in to check the type_product array, whether there is a value from the database there. Everything seems logical, but I can't figure out what's what.

Comment: the problem that `type_product` is relation, and you are passing an array of  string, you should do something like `type_product: { Title: value.type_product}`

Comment: or type_product: `{ Title: { $in: value.type_product}}`

Comment: you passing a title to place where it's expects an object.... you also can change value.type_product to be an array of `[{Title: '....' }, {Title: '...'}]`

Comment: @antokhio I need to use `$and`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I got, thanks `@antokhio`

```js
qs.stringify({
        filters: {
            $and: [
                {
                    weight: {
                        ...(value.weight&&typeof value.weight === "string" && {
                                $between: [15, 30],
                        }),
                        ...(value.weight&&typeof value.weight === "number"&& value.weight<=15 && {

                            $lt: value.weight,

                        }),
                        ...(value.weight&&typeof value.weight === "number"&& value.weight>=30 && {
                            $gt: value.weight,
                        }),
                    }
                },
                {
                    type_product: {
                        Title: {$in: value.type_product}

                    }

                },
                {
                    user_type: {
                        Title: {$in: value.user_type}
                    }

                }
            ],

        },
    }, {
        encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify URL
    });
```